# Can a Slime run?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, alternate-reality

In my world slimes are intelligent creatures of various sizes which can take the shape of anything they like and change color to camouflage.

A slime can camouflage as floor , as a box, a snake or even a person standing up..basically as anything.

Their ability to mimicry is only limited by their talent, the same way an artist is only limited by their visual memories.

A beginner artist with bad memory might have problems drawing people while a talented one can draw hyper realistic things that look like pictures or some that almost look 3D.

The same applies to slimes.

But slimes, being them made out of slimy stuff...how fast can they move? Could a slime replicate a human running motion or would it just collpase on itself?

Comment: Slime is a liquid that would form a puddle without any internal forces. Via what force method can your slime creature take shape and/or move?

Comment: @D.J.Klomp they are made of semi liquid slime, like the real lie example of pulsating slime molds

Comment: So the answer is, as I read it,  that the slime can project force through its skin in a controlled way that is higher than the normal surface tension, correct?

Comment: In a previous similar question it was suggested that some sort of pumps within the slime can shoot fluid forward so the slime can move faster, some sort of structure forming cells could form skeletal structures to keep it stable in human form.

Comment: Are your slimes sticky? Why can't they just form into a wagon-wheel that shifts it's center of gravity forward? Are the surfaces of their body able to be rigid like wood, or firm like rubber, or only mushy like jello? Can they turn into glider shapes and fly? Can they generate an unfilled/underfilled void inside their bodies and become buoyant? I think a lot of your answer depends on what you want them to be able to do.

Comment: It was [designed by Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-1000), therefore it can run.

Comment: Running isn't energy efficient for any slimy critter, they generally prefer short  burst of acceleration such as falling in a fight or flight situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think a slime could roll.**

If a slime has enough internal structural integrity to form a sphere or cylinder, and internally shift its center of mass forward, it could roll.  It might not be rolling like a bowling ball but sort of a flowing slimy roll or a continuous falling forward.    You would need some sort of temporary skeleton - maybe made of microtubules or the like.  That would allow some mass to get leverage against the rest and move itself up and forward.  It would be fast downhill and slow uphill, of course.

I could imagine that a slime in need of rapid locomotion might take some time and rearrange itself into a temporary rolling structure, then cannibalize/recycle the internal framework when it wanted to go back to flowing motions.  On one level this implies a sort of planning, but slime mold are non intelligent and do exactly that, morphing from solitary amoeboid creatures into the multicellular plasmodium according to external cues.

Answer (score 4):

[Granular jamming soft grippers](https://www.pnas.org/content/107/44/18809). 
See [such a gripper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rna03IlJjf8) in action.

Think vacuum packed ground coffee - the pack is hard as brick, the grounds are jammed. Let the air in and it's just ground coffee.

Your slime has jammable granular materials in suspension. Move the granular material into the shape and "suck out" the slime that lubricate the granules and you have a rigid enough structure one can use for running (requires whatever handwave mechanism the slime uses to shift its substance around).

Comment: I would only add that this could work better or worse -- depending on whether you want the running to betray that the slime is not what it appears to be.  If it works well enough, the illusion can be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Think bigger. Think faster.

If they've got the powers of cohesion and movement which real-world slimes do not, and can do the things you suggest, your slimes can move far more rapidly and aggressively.

How about a super-flexible slime sidewinder?

Or a super-bouncy slime kangaroo?

Giant flying slime bat!

Answer (score 2):

If the slime had some sort of small brain, Like an Octopus to allow it to squeeze into tight spaces and taking further inspiration from Octopi and Starfish it could have clusters of nerves throughout the slime which can act like its own mini brain. This will allow it to have a level of intelligence capable of mimicry to high details and the segmented brains can help it form faster and even reform fast if split.

To tackle the structural issues you could compare this to a robotics issue and how nanobots could from complex structures quickly and be stable and functioning. If the slime had specific cells that could join together quickly and form tight bonds, they could form rigid structures, then other cells could form other necessary anatomy like ligaments and muscles. Although the full anatomy may not be necessary so working out how cells could flow within a solid skin or some other internal engineering solution could work.

And as I mentioned in my comment, I quite like the idea of forming pumps, to be able to fire part of its slime quickly, similar to Venom from Marvel.